# Events into android application

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-intent, google-api, android-calendar

This is what I am trying to do. I want to build a app for a particular person and have a module inside the application which would populate all the events/shows that the person is scheduled to perform/performed. I have three approaches in mind - one is google api, another is android calendar and the third is using facebook page of that person. Which one would you think is the best approach? thank you guys.